# Server Error: Configuration must contain `projectId`

Tags: next.js, sanity

I have a local repo of a live NextJS/Sanity website, but I've set the Sanity projectID to a different blank Sanity project to avoid overwriting the live website.

At `http://localhost:3000/`, I'm receiving:

```
Server Error
Error: Configuration must contain `projectId`
```

`lib\client.js` contains:

```
const config = {
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_ID || 'xxxxx',
  dataset: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET || 'production',
  apiVersion: '2021-03-25',
  useCdn: true,
}

const client = sanityClient(config)
```

I've added a CORS origin to my project & there's also a `.env.local.example` in the root folder

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID="xxxxxx"
NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID="sj830cdx"
```

(so not solved by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71460631/667903))

If I rename `env.local.example` to `env.local`  `http://localhost:3000/` will load blank.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught Error: Configuration must contain \`projectId\`( when using environment variable )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71451219/uncaught-error-configuration-must-contain-projectid-when-using-environment-v)

Comment: @Yilmaz, no, I've added a CORS origin to my project and my `.env.local` is in the root folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the error message you received indicates that the `projectId` configuration value is missing in the `config` object used to initialize the `sanityClient`. The projectId is a required configuration parameter for the Sanity client to work properly.
To fix the issue, you can update the `config` object in `lib/client.js` to use `NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID`

```
const config = {
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID || 'xxxxx',
  dataset: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET || 'production',
  apiVersion: '2021-03-25',
  useCdn: true,
}
```

Then, make sure to rename your `.env.local.example` file back to `.env.local` and set the value of `NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID` to the correct project ID for your Sanity project. This should allow the `sanityClient` to initialize correctly and resolve the server error you were seeing.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed `NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_ID` to `NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID`. I still receive a blank page. I think it's because my Sanity project contains no content. I'm having problems with [npm run build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75575749/nextjs-sanity-error-failed-to-collect-page-data) which I need to solve first.

Comment: I've cloned the repo again and kept the original project ID. Working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the sanity import to as below and it worked for me.
import {createClient) from 'next-sanity';
Also I read that the sanityClient configuration is deprecated. Use createClient instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Bryan. When you add code to a question or answer, make sure you enclose it in backticks, and it will be formatted as code when you click Save.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).