# NextJS/Sanity: Error: Failed to collect page data

Tags: next.js, sanity

I have a local repo of a live NextJS/Sanity website, but I've set the Sanity projectID to a different blank Sanity project to avoid overwriting the live website.

After running `npm run build`, I receive an error

```
Error: Failed to collect page data for /industries/[slug]
```

`/pages/industries/[slug].tsx` exists

Help appreciated.

Comment: The error changed to `Error: dataset must be provided to perform queries` when I used the original project ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, cloning the repo again and keeping the original Sanity project ID resolved the error.